# How to specify parameters for input

Tags: python

I want to only allow a user to input a string followed by an integer and separated using a comma and if they do not comply I would like to let them know that they have inputted incorrectly and to let them try again. I am having trouble finding a way to do this, I can make the input require a comma but I do not know how to specify a string and int on each side.

```
name_age = []
user_input = []
name_age2 = []
ages = []

while user_input != "":
    try:
        user_input = input("Type 'Name,Age': ")
        name_age.append(user_input)
        print(name_age)
        if "," not in user_input:
            raise ValueError

    except ValueError:
        print("Incorrect try again")


else:
    name_age.remove("")

    for item in name_age:
        name_age2.append(item.split(','))

    for pair in name_age2:
        for val in pair:
            if val.isdigit():
                ages.append(int(val))

    print(name_age2)
    print(ages)
    print("Names & Ages: ", name_age2)
    print("Total of ages: ", sum(ages))
    print("Average of ages: ", sum(ages) / len(ages))
    print("Total number of names: ", len(name_age2))
    print("End")
```

Comment: could you provide an example of a valid string?

Comment: @collinsuz 'john,24'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can for example make a function to validate the user input, like this.
Here's an example, it's working, but you have to make some modifications.

```
name_age = []
user_input = []
name_age2 = []
ages = []


def validate(input: str) -> bool:
    decomposed_string: str = input.split(',')
    if decomposed_string[1].isdigit() and not decomposed_string[0].isdigit():
        return True
    return False


while user_input != "":
    try:
        user_input = input("Type 'Name,Age': ")
        name_age.append(user_input) if validate(user_input) else print("Incorrect, try again")
        print(name_age)
        if "," not in user_input:
            raise ValueError

    except ValueError:
        print("Incorrect try again")


else:
    name_age.remove("")

    for item in name_age:
        name_age2.append(item.split(','))

    for pair in name_age2:
        for val in pair:
            if val.isdigit():
                ages.append(int(val))

    print(name_age2)
    print(ages)
    print("Names & Ages: ", name_age2)
    print("Total of ages: ", sum(ages))
    print("Average of ages: ", sum(ages) / len(ages))
    print("Total number of names: ", len(name_age2))
    print("End")
```

Comment: Man I tried anding earlier tonight and couldn't get it done, seeing your example helped a lot, I plugged the 'if and not' into my code and was able to drop the exception, thankyou!
`if decomposed_string[1].isdigit() and not decomposed_string[0].isdigit():`

Answer (score 1):

[Regex patterns](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) suits very well for this kind of simple string parsing. Other solution in complex cases would be to go for some third party library [PyParsing](https://pyparsing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [Parsley](https://parsley.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

With regex groups and especially named groups are very handy. Here's a simple example:

```py
name_age_pattern = re.compile(r'(?P<name>\w+),(?P<age>\d+)')

def parse_name_age(string):
    match = name_age_pattern.match(string)
    if not match:
        raise ValueError('input string didnt match pattern')
    return match.group('name'), int(match.group('age'))

name, age = parse_name_age('Jack,23')
```

Then some extra hints. To make your code a little bit more pythonic you could use some classes. Here's a sample:

```py
import re
from typing import NamedTuple

class Person(NamedTuple):
    name: str
    age: int

    name_age_pattern = re.compile(r'(?P<name>\w+),(?P<age>\d+)')

    @classmethod
    def from_string(cls, string):
        match = cls.name_age_pattern.match(string)
        if not match:
            raise ValueError('input string didnt match pattern')
        return cls(match.group('name'), int(match.group('age')))


class People(list):
    # Inheriting from a list should be made with caution. Overriding
    # native functions could result unwanted side effects. We should
    # be safe here since we don't do so.

    @property
    def names(self):
        return ', '.join((person.name for person in self))

    @property
    def total_age(self):
        return sum((person.age for person in self))
    
    @property
    def avg_age(self):
        return self.total_age / len(self)

people = People()
while True:
    input_str = input('Please give a name and age separated by a comma.')
    if input_str == "":
        break
    try:
        people.append(Person.from_string(input_str))
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)

print(people.names)
print(f'sum of ages: {people.total_age}')
print(f'avg of ages: {people.avg_age}')
```

Comment: Thankyou very much, I haven't gotten to regex or classes yet but once I do I will be sure to look back over this and try to rewrite this program more efficiently using this for some practice and learning, thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Here I have used a regex for your condition to validate the input:

```
import re
name_age = []
user_input = []
name_age2 = []
ages = []

while user_input != "":
    try:
        user_input = input("Type 'Name,Age': ")
        name_age.append(user_input)
        print(name_age)
        if not re.search('^\w+(\s+\w+)*,\d+', user_input):
            raise ValueError

    except ValueError:
        print("Incorrect try again")


else:
    name_age.remove("")

    for item in name_age:
        name_age2.append(item.split(','))

    for pair in name_age2:
        for val in pair:
            if val.isdigit():
                ages.append(int(val))

    print(name_age2)
    print(ages)
    print("Names & Ages: ", name_age2)
    print("Total of ages: ", sum(ages))
    print("Average of ages: ", sum(ages) / len(ages))
    print("Total number of names: ", len(name_age2))
    print("End")
```

So this regex would accept names with spaces example "anosha rehan, 12" but if you're looking for only one word names so use this regex `'(\w+)*,\d+'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to match the exact pattern you want from users input.

The regex defined below would match:

`[a-zA-Z]+` - one or more alphabet (both lower and upper case)

`,` - literal comma character

`\d{1,3}` - a range between 1 to 3 digits. `$` must end in digit

```
import re

# input_text_sample = 'john,24'

input_pattern = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z]+,\d{1,3}$')

correct_input = None

while not correct_input:    
    user_input = input("Type 'Name,Age': ")

    correct_input = input_pattern.match(user_input)

    if not correct_input:
        print("Incorrect try again")
    else:
        print(correct_input.string)
```